# Reference about the Conley index theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, dynamical-systems

I'm reading "Isolated invariant sets and the Morse index" by Charles Conley.But I'm lost in some of the concise description or definition.Could you recommend me some references or textbooks for the learning of Conley index theory? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.few.vu.nl/~vdvorst/lectures-2013.pdf is a good set of lecture notes on topological methods in dynamics and includes conley theory.

Answer (score 0):

Mischaikow's [Conley index introduction and survey](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~mischaik/pub_page/paperlist_index.html).